# Python utf8 codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 103:invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, opencsv

Here is my code and sample of my csv file and after I run the code, the error shows up  utf8 codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 103:invalid start byte
and if anyone could help[image: this is the example of the file]

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
h = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/Result.csv')

sentences = h['Mention']

def check_it(sentences):
    if 'camera' in sentences:
        return "Camera"
    if 'Camera' in sentences:
        return "Camera"

    if 'display' in sentences:
        return "Display"
    if 'Display' in sentences:
        return "Display"

    if 'battery' in sentences:
        return "Battery"
    if 'Battery' in sentences:
        return "Battery"

    if 'temperature' in sentences:
        return "Temperature"
    if 'Temperature' in sentences:
        return "Temperature"

    if 'memory' in sentences:
        return "Memory"
    if 'Memory' in sentences:
        return "Memory"

    if 'audio' in sentences:
        return "Audio"
    if 'Audio' in sentences:
        return "Audio"

    if 'design' in sentences:
        return "Design"
    if 'Design' in sentences:
        return "Design"

    return "Others"

h.loc[:, 'Category'] = h.Mention.apply(check_it)

h.to_csv('C:/Desktop/ResultWithCategory.csv')
```

I got error on this code and I dont know why the error shows up

Comment: A screen shot of an Excel sheet doesn't really reveal what bytes are in the CSV file you are trying to import. See the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) for troubleshooting tips and perhaps [edit] your question to show us the actual bytes around the error.

Comment: The question marks where you would expect an apostrophe suggest that the data was wrong even before you wrote it to a CSV file. It is entirely correct for your Python script to refuse to process incorrect input data.

Answer (score 0):

This is unicode conversion error, try this...

h = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/Result.csv', encoding = "utf-8")